# How to add a string before all values in a column-- Using Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this:

```
field1,field2
dummydata,dummydata
dummydata,dummydata
dummydata,dummydata
dummydata,dummydata
```

I want to write a Redshift Query to adds v1_ to the beginning of each value in field1. The output would look like this:

```
field1,field2
v1_dummydata,dummydata
v1_dummydata,dummydata
v1_dummydata,dummydata
v1_dummydata,dummydata
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how I would go about this. I am new to redshift so this is new to me.

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Hint:  `||` is the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tbl(field1,field2
dummydata,dummydata
dummydata,dummydata
dummydata,dummydata
dummydata,dummydata)

Update tbl
set field1 = 'v1_'+field1
```